# Trying to send email based on checkbox selections

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send emails automatically if the checkboxes in Column P are not checked. I barely know enough about code to get in trouble. The code I have has been Frankensteined together, so I know I'm missing something but I'm too new at this to understand what. If I run the code as-is, an email is sent if there is an email address listed in Column L, but it is sent regardless of if Column P is checked or not. I don't want an email sent if the checkbox is checked. I've searched through the forums and have tried to piece together a solution that works for me but I just keep hitting a wall. I know the problem lies with identifying the checkbox and that's where I'm getting lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: function sendEmail() {



var message=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Message');
var subject = message.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var message = message.getRange(2,2).getValue();
Logger.log(subject)

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TRACKER");
Logger.log(sheet)
var data = sheet.getDataRange().offset(1,0).getValues();


data.forEach(function (row) {
  if (row[0] == ""){
    Logger.log("is null")
  }

Comment: else{
    Logger.log(row)
    var emailAddress = row[11]
    Logger.log(emailAddress)
    var name = row[14]
    var numb = row[13]
    var date = row[4]
    date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "BST" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );
    var days = row[10]
    var staff = row[8]
    var time = row[5]
    var submitted = row[12]

Comment: time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT" , "HH:mm" );
    var message1=message.replace("<Prisoner Name>",name).replace("<Prisoner Number>",numb).replace("<date>",date).replace("<days>",days).replace("<staff>",staff).replace("<time>",time).replace("<Paperwork>",submitted);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message1);
    Logger.log("sent")
  }
})
}

Comment: You should not add your code in the comments, rather it should be within your question. Also, it is always good practice to share a spreadsheet with dummy data showing what you're trying to do

Comment: Post code in question and provide dummy data in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "TRUE" && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    let [e,s,m] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,3).getValues().flat();
    MailApp.sendEmail(e,s,m);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Sheet:

[image]

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)